# Pixel-based Email Tracking

Tags: javascript, email, gmail, tracking

I've been working on a mass mailing system with email tracking. However, I discovered that Gmail's image proxy feature interferes with pixel-based tracking.

If you have any tips or workarounds for accurate tracking, please comment below. Your expertise is highly appreciated!

This is the tracking pixel I've been using:

```
<img src="https://server.xxx/api/track/${email.uuid}" />
```

And I've been using this get call to return the pixel:

````
const email = await Email.findOne({ uuid: req.params.uuid });
    if (email) {
        email.opens.push({ openedAt: new Date() });
        await email.save();
    }
    const img = new Buffer.from("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7", "base64");
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "image/gif",
        "Content-Length": img.length,
    });
    res.end(img);
    ```
````